# Load ajax success data on new page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, jsp

My ajax call hits the controller and fetches a complete JSP page on success. I was trying to load that data independently on a new page rather than within some element of the existing page. I tried loading it for an html tag but that didn't work either. I tried skipping the success function but it remained on the same page without success data. My ajax call is made on clicking a normal button in the form and the code looks like as shown below.

```
$.ajax({

    url : '/newpage',
    type : 'POST',
    data : requestString,
    dataType : "text",
    processData : false,
    contentType : false,
    success : function(completeHtmlPage) {
        alert("Success");
        $("#html").load(completeHtmlPage);
    },
    error : function() {
        alert("error in loading");
    }

});
```

Comment: Why don't you use `window.location.href = '/newpage';` to redirect to the page?

Comment: two questions: 1. did you see the `alert("Success")`? 2. could you please add your html code, specially `#html` part?

Comment: have you ever HEARD about LINKS?

Comment: this is not how you use [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/), please read the jQuery API doc again

Comment: On success Redirect the page

Comment: @Cymen i can't use that as my the newpage requires dynamic data which is bein handled by controller right now.

Comment: @VishalPatel i dont want to redirect to a new page. i want to load the page that i got in success

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do:

```
$.ajax({

url : '/newpage',
type : 'POST',
data : requestString,
dataType : "text",
processData : false,
contentType : false,
success : function(completeHtmlPage) {
    alert("Success");
    $("html").empty();
    $("html").append(completeHtmlPage);

},
error : function() {
    alert("error in loading");
}

});
```

Comment: Thanks. Option 1 works perfect for me. Though i use it like this instead $("html").empty(); $("html").append(completeHtmlPage).
The option 2 seems to be an incorrect solution as it loads my HtmlContent in the Url resulting in page not found error.

Comment: that means **completeHtmlPage** is not URL but the content..if you found my answer correct please accept it as an answer..:)

Comment: Yes you are right, i have mentioned the same in my question, completeHtmlPage is HTML content. Thanks for the answer. can you please remove the option 2 so that i can accept this as the answer?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this,

```js
my_window = window.open("");
my_window.document.write(completeHtmlPage);
```

into your success.